Remaining Accounts lifetime
I have problem of borrowing accounts mutably from remaining accounts. Not exactly how to use AccountInfo, as error says that accounts does not live long enough.
I am using Anchor 0.29, Solana-Program 0.17.4.
Previously it was working, after upgrade AccountInfo started falling with lifetime issue.
Tried a bunch of stuff even tried to use std::mem::replace accounts, but nothing helped so far.
This is the function I am trying to fix, I know it does not do anything meaningful yet, but I am trying to fix lifetime issue here:
fn swap_spl<'info>(
    authority: &AccountInfo<'info>,
    remaining_accounts: &mut Iter<AccountInfo<'info>>,
    scratch: &mut Scratch,
) -> Result<AccountInfo<'info>> {     
    let accounts: Vec<AccountInfo<'info>> = remaining_accounts.take(7).cloned().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    SplSwapInfo::try_accounts(
        // Will be validated by the spl swap registry
        &Pubkey::default(),
        &mut &accounts[..],
        &[],
        &mut SplSwapInfoBumps::default(),
        &mut scratch.reallocs,
    )?;

    Ok(authority.to_account_info())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SplSwapInfo<'info> {
    /// CHECK:
    pub swap_pool: AccountInfo<'info>,

    /// CHECK:
    pub authority: AccountInfo<'info>,

    /// CHECK:
    #[account(mut)]
    pub vault_a: AccountInfo<'info>,

    /// CHECK:
    #[account(mut)]
    pub vault_b: AccountInfo<'info>,

    /// CHECK:
    #[account(mut)]
    pub token_mint: AccountInfo<'info>,

    /// CHECK:
    #[account(mut)]
    pub fee_account: AccountInfo<'info>,

    /// The address of the swap program
    /// CHECK:
    pub swap_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
}


I tried using 'a:'info with &'a AccountInfo<'info> and even wise versa, does not help.
Tried std::mem::replace accounts, does not help.
Tried removing 'info lifetime at all, does not help.

The error itself is:
 error[E0597]: `accounts` does not live long enough
    |
    | fn swap_spl<'info>(
    |             ----- lifetime `'info` defined here
...
    |     let accounts: Vec<AccountInfo<'info>> = remaining_accounts.take(7).cloned().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    |         --------  ----------------------- type annotation requires that `accounts` is borrowed for `'info`
    |         |
    |         binding `accounts` declared here
...
    |         &mut &accounts[..],
    |               ^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
    | }
    | - `accounts` dropped here while still borrowed


BTW I tried using Rc::RefCell. Does not help though. I saw that AccountInfo uses it a lot. For example for data field.

I think I found the issue, but not sure why it was changed and how to fix it. The issue is in the instructions::spl_token_swap::SplSwapInfo fn try_accounts(__program_id: &anchor_lang::solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey, __accounts: &mut &'info [anchor_lang::solana_program::account_info::AccountInfo<'info>], __ix_data: &[u8], __bumps: &mut SplSwapInfoBumps, __reallocs: &mut std::collections::BTreeSet<anchor_lang::solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey>) -> anchor_lang::Result<Self> Lifetime of the __accounts. I can not change signature of the Accounts::try_accounts, so I don't know the fix.

This question is similar to: Lifetime error after upgrade of Anchor and Solana. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Sorry for mixing things probably, but it is not related to the Context or instruction handler. It specifically problem when using with Accounts::try_accounts, at least in my case.

The point is that try_accounts function signature is similar to: fn mock<'info>(acc: &'info [AccountInfo<'info>]) {     for item in acc {         println!("mock {:?}", item);     } } which actually fails, but if you will make it like: fn mock<'info>(acc: &[AccountInfo<'info>]) {     for item in acc {         println!("mock {:?}", item);     } } then everything works. So extra 'info lifetime breaks it.

I found some workaround, but not sure if that is a good way of doing it: let remaining_accounts: &[AccountInfo] = unsafe { transmute(accounts.as_slice()) }; This way you provide the type which is expected by Anchor.

This is the PR which would probably fix it: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/2770
